# WordPress REST API - Is there a way to return category and parent category name inside of posts response?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

Basically what I need is to get `category_name` and `parent_category_name` for each post in response for `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Under `categories` it only returns array of category IDs. That's not an option since there is a lot of categories and subcategories to map all that stuff.

[image: Post Categories screenshot]

With parameter `_embed` I can get `"wp:term"` but it's not exactly what I need. It returns arrays of categories and tags both combined and sometimes it won't return the parent category.

Any solutions? Should I keep going on through the documentation or is there any function to extend the WordPress REST API response?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways to manipulate the WP Rest API with the information you need.

One way would be to `filter` the `post` object in REST directly, using the [`rest_prepare_{$post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_prepare_this-post_type/) filter

Another would be to register a new "REST field" with the [`register_rest_field`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/) function.

Using the first one, you could do something as simple as getting the category names and dropping them in as a new data field:

```
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'my_filter_post', 10, 3 );
function my_filter_post( $data, $post, $context ){

    // Does this have categories?
    if( !empty($data->data['categories']) ){

        // Loop through them all
        foreach( $data->data['categories'] as $category_id ){
            // Get the actual Category Object
            $category = get_category( $category_id );

            if( $category->parent == 0 ){
                // "top level" category
                $data->data['parent_category'] = $category->name;
            } else {
                // some child level category
                $data->data['child_category'] = $category->name;
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Using the REST field option would look something like this [WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287931/get-the-category-name-instead-of-id-from-wp-api), though you'd of course need to iterate over the categories to see which is the parent and which is the child, etc.

In either case, you may need to adjust the logic and use something like the [`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) function or one of the [many "get hierarchical cat/terms" answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14652/how-to-show-a-hierarchical-terms-list), especially if you've got more than a "parent > child" relationship, or multiple levels of categories on each post - but `rest_prepare_{$post_type}` or `register_rest_field` should be able to get your desired result pretty easily.

Comment: I've tried the above filter solution and it worked @Xhynk. Thanks but now I have bigger problem. Im not familiar with php so im asking here if there is any fast solution. 

What if I had multiple categories per post. [for example](https://imgur.com/ezJTan9)
So here are three parent categories containing 5+ sub-categories each and each post has at least one sub-category of each parent selected. So then you get 3 id's randomly ordered.

The output would be again parent_name -> child_name or an array of nested category names. Maybe you have an idea?